# ExecutorService :How to put the lists returned by multiple callables in into a parent list?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a callable which is executing taking different list of parameters and returning another list. I want the list returned by each thread to be added onto a list.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Java 8 parallel stream.

```
List<List<Something>> listOfLists = ...
List<List<Result>> results = listOfLists.parallelStream()
                                       .map(l -> function(l))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However you can use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es = 
List<Callable<List<Result>>> callables =

List<Future<List<Result>>> futures = es.invokaAll(callables);
List<List<Result>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (Future<List<Result>> future : futures)
    results.add(future.get());
```

Comment: Thanks.Can you provide more clarity on how to add the callables.

Comment: @Likhith since it is your requirement I assume you know the details of why using Callable is simpler than the first solution which doesn't need them.